# Flutter SQL flite - The non-nullable variable '_database' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression

Tags: sql, database, flutter, dart, sqflite

## How can I fix this issue

I'm getting this error and wondering if there's a better approach to the problem.
**Error Message**
static Database database; // The non-nullable variable 'database' must be initialized.

I will be much glad if anyone can help me fix the issue.
Code below:

Comment: Sure. Don't do what you did. There are better alternatives. But there is really no way of suggesting one, if you only tell us what you did wrong, and don't tell us what you *want* to do.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have shared your code, thought the solution seems to be simple.
Your variable **_database** can't store null values by default.

So instead of this:

```
DATATYPE _database;
```

Try using

```
DATATYPE? _database;
```

`Look at the '?', it denotes that value can be null`, and your code should be good to go. :)

Also try reading about [**Null Safety**](https://dart.dev/null-safety)